# How to write unit test case for error validation of checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I have scenario where when the user clicks on the Next button without agreeing the terms i should throw an error saying 'please agree the terms',so i need to write a unit test case for it using Jest and React Testing Library.How can i achieve that.

```
import Terms from "./Terms";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Terms />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const { useState } = require("react");

function Terms() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(false);
  const onNext = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (checked !== true) {
      setErrorMessage(true);
    } else {
      setErrorMessage(false);
    }
  };
  const handleCheckBoxChange = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    const result = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).checked;
    setChecked(result);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Terms</h1>
      <input type="checkbox" value={checked} onChange={handleCheckBoxChange} />
      <label>click to agree the terms</label>
      <br />
      {errorMessage && <p>Please agree the terms before proceeding</p>}
      <button onClick={onNext}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Terms;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first break it down. You want a test that does the following things, one after the other:

1. renders your `Terms` component
2. finds a button labelled "Next"
3. clicks the button
4. finds the error text on the screen

You can use react-testing-library to grab the elements you need, and user-event-testing-library to interact with them.

Add both libraries as dependencies to your project, and try the following, importing the things you need to get it working:

```
it("error shows when terms not agreed", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  render(<Terms />)

  const nextButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /next/i });
  await user.click(nextButton);
  
  expect(screen.getByText(/please agree the terms before proceeding/i)).toBeVisible()
})
```

You probably want a similar test for your happy case too, where you agree the terms before clicking the button.

Comment: Yes, I want a similar similar test, where you agree the terms before clicking the button. How can that be achieved?

Comment: You can follow the same steps as above. You want to write a test that (1) renders your Terms component, (2) find the checkbox and the Next button, (3) clicks the checkbox, (4) clicks the button, (5) doesn't find any error text. The role for a checkbox is simply `checkbox`. You can also expect something `.not.toBeInTheDocument()` if it shouldn't be visible.